# Laravel Eloquent - take results randomly from whereIn

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Laravel version 4.2

I'm having issues with this one problem I have.
I need to fill a quota of 5 results however I only have an array size of 3. I also need the rows to be selected randomly from the Array.

*edit: Fetching all results is not feasible

```
    $store_id_array = array('111', '222' , '333');

    $reviews = Review::whereIn('store_id', $store_id_array)
                      ->take(5)
                      ->get();

    return Response::json($reviews);
```

This will return 5 results however only from the first item in the array.
How do I select randomly from the array items?

Comment: @thmspl Might be legacy code combined with no budget for an upgrade. It's a good recommendation to stay up to date with Laravel, but not always possible.

Answer (score 2):

#### For Laravel below version 5:

`orderBy(DB::raw('RAND()'))` like this:

```php
$reviews = Review::whereIn('store_id', $store_id_array)
                      ->orderBy(DB::raw('RAND()'))
                      ->take(5)
                      ->get();
```

#### For Laravel 5.0 +

use `inRandomOrder()` method:

```php
$reviews = Review::whereIn('store_id', $store_id_array)
                      ->inRandomOrder()
                      ->take(5)
                      ->get();
```

Comment: This will still only order results from '111' randomly not from the full list in the array, thanks for your contribution.

Comment: This query should work. Could it be possible that you have too many records with `store_id` `111` in your database and so not enough `222` and `333` to be consistently  retrieved ?

Comment: This is same as query `select * from review where store_id in (111, 222, 333) order by RAND() limit 5` which should be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
     public function index()
        {
           $categories = Category::latest()->get();
           $protfolios = Protfolio::all();
 $randompost = Post::approved()->publish()->take(4)->InRandomOrder()->get();
            $allposts = Post::where('price', 0)->approved()->publish()->take(8)->get();
            $posts = Post::latest()->where('price', '>=', 0)->approved()->publish()->take(8)->get();

            $latestposts = Post::latest()->approved()->publish()->take(8)->get();
            return view('welcome',compact('posts','randompost ','categories','allposts','latestposts','protfolios'));
        }
```